# Django - Pandas - add_format: cell get format but only applied if enter keys is pressed

Tags: django, pandas

I have a django function in the backend that collect some numbers from a database using a for loop, set the format for the workbook with *workbook.add_format* and write to a spreadsheet that get then downloaded. the Spreadsheet is generated and populated using the pandas library.
This is the core of my code:

```
native_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00;[Red]-#,##0.00'})

        for index, wp_number in enumerate(df['WP no.']):
            # workpackets' row index start at row=1
            row = index + 1

            worksheet.write_number(row, 5, df['Invoice total'][index], formats[-1])
            worksheet.write_number(row, 6, df['Against this WP'][index], native_format)
```

the format is correctly applied to the cells but when i download and open the spreadsheet the following happens:

[image]

As you can see the format is applied as custom and not number. Only if I select a cell and press enter the format is recognised and applied:

[image]

How can I can make the format to automatically apply to all cells?
Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the dtype of `'Invoice total'` and `'Against this WP'`?

Comment: All columns are type object

Comment: Change them to numeric and try again?